# Converting a Text File into Excel using Talend

Tags: excel, hadoop, text, hive, talend

i'm currently working on a talend project to load a tweet log into hive table. But due to the unstructured format of the text file, i had to process it into a structured file first, in this case im converting it to csv, making it separated by commas.

I managed to split the columns as follow.
[image]

And this is my Talend Job.
[image]

This is the text file i'm working with.
[image]

I am trying to make the highlighted portion as a single column.
Due to the configuration of separation by space in the file input,
it split the tweets. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to view raw data with the Windows Notepad since line breaks could be omitted. You should rather open it with Notepad++ for example. Anyways, please do not add screenshots of data but [edit] your question and add a few rows of (pseudo) data.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is very hard to parse since your separator (space) is also present in your data.  If possible, it would be best to fix it at the source.  But since that is not always feasible, here's what I could come up with :

[image]

The idea is to insert a newline character (or any other character(s) not already present in your data) in front of each date in your text (since that is the most unique pattern). Next normalize it using the newline character (or the one you used in the replace) in a `tNormalize`, so that you have on each line a string containing a date, a username and the tweet.

The quick and dirty regex I put together to match the date is :

```
(\\w{3}\\s\\w{3}\\s\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s\\w{3}\\s\\d{4})
```

And replace with a carriage return followed by the date that was matched : `\n$1`

Next, `tExtractRegexFields` uses another regex in order to extract the date, username, and the tweet each in its own column. Here's the regex I used :

```
(\\w{3}\\s\\w{3}\\s\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s\\w{3}\\s\\d{4}\\s)\\(([^\\)]+)\\)\\s(.+)
```

There are 3 capturing groups, one for the date, one for the username, and the last one captures all text after that which is the tweet.

In my example, I used this text :

```
"Fri Mar 15 23:58:55 CET 2013 (iMezouar) this is the 1st tweetFri Mar 15 23:58:55 CET 2013 (username2) this is the 2nd tweetFri Mar 15 23:58:55 CET 2013 (username3) this is the 3rd tweet"
```

And I got :

```
.-----------------------------+---------+----------------------.
|                          tLogRow_2                           |
|=----------------------------+---------+---------------------=|
|date                         |username |tweet                 |
|=----------------------------+---------+---------------------=|
|Fri Mar 15 23:58:55 CET 2013 |iMezouar |this is the 1st tweet |
|Fri Mar 15 23:58:55 CET 2013 |username2|this is the 2nd tweet |
|Fri Mar 15 23:58:55 CET 2013 |username3|this is the 3rd tweet"|
'-----------------------------+---------+----------------------'
```

Comment: I think there might be line breaks at the end of the line which would make the matching a bit easier.

Comment: If that is the case, then the `tReplace` and `tNormlize` could be omitted, the `tExtractRegexFields` will do the job of parsing the columns :)